# Keeping screen on, which way?

Tags: android, screen

I have found two ways on keeping the screen on:

First one is simpler:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Second one is using a wakelock and requiring an extra permission:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);  
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");
```

Is there any real difference between this two methods apart from the second one being more complicated to implement and requiring an extra permission? Will the end result be always the same?

Comment: *If* one needs a permission and the other doesn't, there **is** certainly a difference (or a bug in the API). What difference, however, I don't know.

Comment: The permission probably is there because you can do more powerful things with that, not only keep the screen on. I was just wondering more about the end result, if both ways will always keep the screen on no matter what.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should see [Coding for (Battery) Life](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/CodingLifeBatteryLife.html) Google IO presentation, slide 16

If you don't want to, then: You could do the first one in the XML for any layout element and it is the suggested one to use (don't know about applying it to the window though, might be as bad as the wakelock, I don't know).

**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
```

**Window Flag:**

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the xml way. I think it is almost equivalent to the window one. However in the presentation it says that wakelocks are costly if forgotten. So if done right they should be ok.
It seems that the end result would be the same. I will choose the recommended way then.

Comment: @JanS. you should watch the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=OUemfrKe65c#t=1793 (on 29:53) . using a wakelock and its permission in case you just have a UI based app isn't needed and is very problematic in case you have bugs or crashes. if you use this flag instead, you avoid using a wakelock yet keep the screen on as long as the user stays on the current layout.