# How to enable or disable autolock in android?

Tags: android

I have one toggle button which desides to enable and disable autolock in app,so how can we do that in app pls help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is autolock? care to elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by autolock you mean stop the phone from turning the screen off due to a period of inactivity then you can do the following:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");
```

to stop the screen from 'locking':

```
wl.acquire();
```

to allow it to lock again:

```
wl.release();
```

Answer (score 12):

Do NOT use the wakelocks. You might not release it and then you can drain the battery and annoy the user. And it requires additional permissions.

Instead do this in onCreate():

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: It looks like there's more about this here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771811/keeping-screen-on-which-way

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about your question but, i think it refer to keep a application always on.

Check this site:
[PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)