# Android View.setKeepScreenOn() - does it apply when the view is GONE?

Tags: android, view, gps, visible

I have a View with some GPS info. It is made `VISIBLE`/`GONE` with a GPS on/off switch inside the app. I want to call `setKeepScreenOn(true)` on this view so that it keeps screen on but ONLY when it is `VISIBLE` and NOT when it is `GONE`.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't say what your problem is, although one might suspect it's the fact that there's no `View.setScreenOn()`? How about http://stackoverflow.com/a/2772015/1856738

Comment: Typo, I mean setKeepScreenOn(). Just fixed the question. Actually i don't have a problem. The very brief android docs are the problem :)

Comment: It's not a duplicate and the question is very concrete and specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it also applies when the view is gone, but I don't know. It shouldn't be hard to test though.

But you can just use `View.setKeepScreenOn(false)` whenever you're setting its visibility to `GONE` and `View.setKeepScreenOn(true)` whenever you're setting its visibility to `VISIBLE`.

```
View view = ...; // I guess something with findViewById() happens here
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
view.setKeepScreenOn(false);
...
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.setKeepScreenOn(true);
```

Or that you don't have to keep that in mind, you could define a method for that:

```
private void mySetVisibility(View v, int visibility) {
    v.setVisibility(visibility);
    if (visibility == View.GONE) {
        v.setKeepScreenOn(false);
    } else {
        v.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    }
}
```

and then just use `mySetVisibility(view, View.GONE)` and `mySetVisibility(view, View.VISIBLE)`.

Pretty straightforward.

Hope it helps.